# Coda 2: the "plugin" menu in the top bar vanished

Tags: macos, coda

For some reason the "plugin" menu item vanished from [`coda`](http://panic.com/coda/). It should be near the item "window". Any idea how to fix this?

Edit:

I'm running Mac OS x (ver 10.7.5).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never seen that, but I'd suggest reinstalling.  If it persists I'd go in a delete all your plugins (maybe one is corrupt) or temporarily relocate them.

Plugins are stored in:
~/Library/Application Support/Coda 2/Plug-ins/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any plugins, it will be invisible. Try installing a plugin and see what happens ;)

Comment: This is not an answer but merely a comment. Please use the comment function when you have enough reputation.

Comment: @UwePlonus I see an attempt to answer the question here. If the menu is not shown when there are no plugins, this is the solution, so it doesn't need to be deleted.